# Generic calculation functions that support also Decimal

Tags: swift, generics, floating-point, decimal, nsdecimalnumber

### In short

I was playing with calculations to analyse reliability and error propagation with different numeric type when high precision matters.  The same formula being applied to different numeric types, I tried to use generics but was not able to cover also the `Decimal` type.

Is there a way to have a single generic implementation covering `Float`, `Double` and `Decimal` for simple numeric functions ?

### More details

The calculation is based on the [Muller sequence](https://medium.com/the-technical-archaeologist/is-cobol-holding-you-hostage-with-math-5498c0eb428b) that applies a very simple formula recursively. The code for the three considered type is:

```
func mullerFormulaDouble(y:Double, z:Double ) -> Double {
    return 108.0 - ( (815.0-1500.0/z)/y)
}
func mullerFormulaFloat(y:Float, z:Float ) -> Float {
    return 108.0 - ( (815.0-1500.0/z)/y)
}
func mullerFormulaDecimal(y:Decimal, z:Decimal ) -> Decimal {
    return Decimal(108) - ( (Decimal(815)-Decimal(1500)/z)/y)
}
```

The generic calculation looks like:

```
func mullerFormula<T>(y:T, z:T ) -> T {      // a constraint is required for T
    let a = T(1500)/z
    let b = (T(815) - a)/y
    return T(108) - b
}
print (mullerFormula(y:4.0, z:4.24))
print (mullerFormula(y:Float(4.0), z:Float(4.24)))
print (mullerFormula(y:Decimal(4), z:Decimal(sign:.plus, exponent: -2, significand:424)))
```

The code above did not compile, due to an error message about `T` having no initializer, which makes sense. Some [type constraint](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Generics.html#ID186) is required to make it work.  So I used `T:Numeric`, but it failed on the division, with the error that it cannot be applied to operands `T?` and `T`.

A couple of errors later, I ended up with `T:FloatingPoint`. It then worked for `Double` and `Float`, but I can still not use it with `Decimal`, because `Decimal` does not conform to `FloatingPoint`.  I didn't find any other suitable common protocol for my type constraint.

Considering that  all these three numeric types support initialization from an integer and the four basic operations, I cannot imagine that there is not way to write a generic function to cover them all.  Hence my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Method 1: Define a `BasicNumeric` protocol with the functions you require**

Here is one way to do it.  Create a `protocol` called `BasicNumeric` that has the common properties of the types you want to use.  Declare that your types implement that protocol, and use that protocol as the constraint in your new function:

```
protocol BasicNumeric: ExpressibleByIntegerLiteral {
    static func +(_: Self, _: Self) -> Self
    static func -(_: Self, _: Self) -> Self
    static func *(_: Self, _: Self) -> Self
    static func /(_: Self, _: Self) -> Self
}

extension Double:  BasicNumeric { }
extension Float:   BasicNumeric { }
extension Decimal: BasicNumeric { }

func mullerFormula<T: BasicNumeric>(y:T, z:T ) -> T {
    let a = 1500/z
    let b = (815 - a)/y
    return 108 - b
}

print (mullerFormula(y:4.0, z:4.24))
print (mullerFormula(y:Float(4.0), z:Float(4.24)))
print (mullerFormula(y:Decimal(4), z:Decimal(sign:.plus, exponent: -2, significand:424)))
```

*Output:*

```
-7.306603773584911
-7.3066025
-7.30660377358490566037735849056603775
```

---

**Method 2: Defining `Divisible` protocol and using `Numeric` protocol**

Leo Dabus offered this alternate implementation in the comments.

```
protocol Divisible {
    static func /(_: Self, _: Self) -> Self
}

extension Double:  Divisible { }
extension Float:   Divisible { }
extension Decimal: Divisible { }

func mullerFormula<T: Numeric & Divisible>(y: T, z: T) -> T {
    let a = 1500 / z
    let b = (815 - a) / y
    return 108 - b
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this awesome answer!  Protocol extension is a really nice thing.  I could  finish, addressing also the recursive part that added some comparisons and absolute value.  It worked making the `BasicNumeric:Comparable,SignedNumeric` and keeping only its / operation as +,-,* are covered by SignedNumeric.

Comment: No need to require an `Int` initializer. Just add `ExpressibleByIntegerLiteral` to the method signature

Comment: I would just create a Divisible protocol `protocol Divisible { static func /(_: Self, _: Self) -> Self }` and use Numeric constraint.

Comment: `extension Decimal: Divisible { }`
`extension Double: Divisible { }`
`extension Float: Divisible { }` `func mullerFormula<T: Numeric & Divisible & ExpressibleByIntegerLiteral>(y: T, z: T) -> T {` `let a = 1500 / z` `let b = (815 - a) / y` `return 108 - b`
`}`

Comment: Actually `ExpressibleByIntegerLiteral` at the method signature is not even needed. `Numeric` protocol inherits from it. `Numeric & Divisible` would suffice

Comment: @LeoDabus, thanks for your suggestions.  I added them to the answer because they are clearer to see with syntax highlighting.